# getting an error while creating a label using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

i tried to create a label using this meathod but got this error
label.pack(side=TOP,fill=X)
NameError: name 'label' is not defined

````
class pharma:
    def __init__(self,root) :
         self.root=root
         self.root.title("Pharmacy management System") #title 
         self.root.geometry("1520x800+0+0") #dimensions 
          
         label = Label(self.root, text = "Pharmacy management System", bg = "green", bd = 15, fg = "white", font = "Castellar")  
    label.pack(side=TOP,fill=X) 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=Tk()
    obj=pharma(root)
    root.mainloop()```
````

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your indentation. --> label.pack(side=TOP,fill=X)  is not right indented. Here is the right way, how it should work:

```
class pharma:
def __init__(self,root) :
     self.root=root
     self.root.title("Pharmacy management System") #title 
     self.root.geometry("1520x800+0+0") #dimensions 
      
     label = Label(self.root, text = "Pharmacy management System", bg = "green", bd = 15, fg = "white", font = "Castellar")  
     label.pack(side=TOP,fill=X)
```

Comment: is it not same to mine???

Comment: @SanskarTyagi No, they are not the same.  Indentation of code matters in Python.  So this answer has indentation issue on the `def __init__(...)` function.  And yours on `label.pack(...)`.